# How to give delay between Item and Item on Listview.builder() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

```dart
import 'package:calendar_app/constants/customColor.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/models/announcement.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/services/getAnnouncement.dart';
import 'package:calendar_app/widgets/announcementItem.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Announcement extends StatefulWidget {
  const Announcement({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Announcement> createState() => _AnnouncementState();
}

class _AnnouncementState extends State<Announcement>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Future<List<AnnouncementItem>> announcements = getAnnouncement();

  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    vsync: this,
  )..forward();

  late final Animation<double> _fadeAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
  );

  late final Animation<Offset> _animation = CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.elasticOut,
  ).drive(Tween(begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.4), end: Offset.zero));
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: CustomColor.pastelBlue,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40, vertical: 20),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<AnnouncementItem>>(
          future: announcements,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final announcements = snapshot.data!;
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: announcements.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return FadeTransition(
                      opacity: _fadeAnimation,
                      child: SlideTransition(
                        position: _animation,
                        child: AnnouncementListItem(
                          announcement: snapshot.data![index],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('No announcements found.'),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

1. call getAnnouncement();
2. assign controller and animations
3. loading indicator by FutureBuilder
4. if there is a snapData then return Listview.builder()
5. AnnouncementListItem wrapped by FadeTransition and SlideTransition

I found out the package but I just wanted to implement by myself tho

I want to apply each transition Effect on Each Item. but it doesn't let me...

I want to implement like this package Effect
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. have a look at the github code of flutter_staggered_animation and see how the package creators solved the problem. However, since it is a package and it includes several different animations that might be a bit too complicated for what you are trying to achieve.
2. use [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) instead of ListView. It's flutter's class for list views that need animations for their list items. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72988679/how-can-i-add-delay-between-items-in-listview-builder) to see how you can add delays